# JAX-WS Provider with attachment streaming

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, attachment, mtom

I would like to implement a JAX-WS Provider, that receives large MTOM attachments. I would like to prevent the attachments from being cached in memory; I would like to stream them to a temporary file (or the JAX-WS implementation to stream them to a temporary file).

Theoretically I could get the MTOM attachmments with SOAPMessage#getAttachments(), or with WebServiceContext#getMessageContext()#get(INBOUND_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS), and stream them into a temporary file.

The problem is that I've found no way to get the SOAP Part itself without the attachments resolved (in memory). I've tried the PAYLOAD/MESSAGE annotations, Source/SOAPMessage parameters, but no luck, the memory always gets filled with the attachments.

Does anyone have an idea, or experience about this problem?